# The EntityCommand.CommandText value must be of the form 'ContainerName.FunctionImportName'

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have searched on Google atleast 3 hours but i get all the answers for this issue that are relevant to ADO.NET but i am using Entity framework with visual studio 2012 and mysql.

I want to call a stored procedure having 1 parameter and what i did:

- I updated model from database selecting all the stored procedures.
- then i created function imports
- and finally i wrote following code to call that stored procedure.

  **My Controller Function Body**

  {
       db.SetRecipientsToRefferalPayments(new ObjectParameter("referralId", referralId));
  }

**My Auto generated class (Model.Context.cs)**

```
public virtual int SetRecipientsToRefferalPayments(ObjectParameter referralId)
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SetRecipientsToRefferalPayments", referralId);
        }
```

**and i get following error:**
The value of EntityCommand.CommandText is not valid for a StoredProcedure command. The EntityCommand.CommandText value must be of the form 'ContainerName.FunctionImportName'.

any one guide me how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It was a very strange problem after spending 2-3 hours finally i figured out the solution.

**Steps To Resolve That Issue:**

1) Click on [Model].Context.tt File
2) Open with  XML Editor or any text editor
3) CTRL + G to location line Number 288 or 277 that was in my case
4) Or Locate following function "**ExecuteFunction**"

```
public string ExecuteFunction(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
{
    var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);
    var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction);

    var callParams = _code.StringBefore(", ", String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray()));
    if (includeMergeOption)
    {
        callParams = ", mergeOption" + callParams;
    }

    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction{0}(\"{1}\"{2});",
        returnType == null ? "" : "<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
        edmFunction.Name,
        callParams);
}
```

5) change **edmFunction.Name** to **edmFunction.FullName** which is the second last line of this function and run your code :)

I faced this issue in EF5 hoping for Microsoft to fix this issue in future EF versions.

Comment: This. This right here. I can confirm this fix works on the latest ver. of EF. Why this hasn't been fixed  yet I don't know, but this just saved my code using EF 6.1.3.

Comment: Bug thumbs up from me - just ran into exactly this migrating a huge solution to dbContext from ObjectContext. Last thing I need at this stage is weirdness like this!

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this error as well and it turned out to be the connection strings. In my situation I had two separate entity models that had the same entity model name.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EntityModelNameEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://My.Namespace.FirstOne/EntityModelName.csdl|res://My.Namespace.FirstOne/EntityModelName.ssdl|res://My.Namespace.FirstOne/EntityModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=....&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="OtherModelEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModelName.csdl|res://*/EntityModelName.ssdl|res://*/EntityModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=....&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When OtherModelEntities was trying to find the model resources it ended up matching on the one in My.Namespace.FirstOne due to the use of the * wildcard matching. To correct this I updated the OtherModelEntities connection string to include the namespace like this:

```
<add name="OtherModelEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://My.Namespace.SecondOne/EntityModelName.csdl|res://My.Namespace.SecondOne/EntityModelName.ssdl|res://My.Namespace.SecondOne/EntityModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=....&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: More correctly it should be assembly name, not a namespace. See [Model and Mapping File Locations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't solve my problem but I found another way and it was solved.

If It couldn't solve your problem you can try that:

```
ExecuteFunction<MyClass>("YourDbContextName.YourProcedureName",parameters);
```